# How to autocomplete or find file with special character almost impossible to type?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, keyboard-layout

In bash, I make use of the autocomplete with <kbd>TAB</kbd> feature a lot, and sometimes I have filenames starting with special characters that I can't type with my default keyboard layout.

My question is, how can I find a filename starting with a character which is *almost* impossible to type with an English keyboard? For example, if the filename starts with a Japanese character, like `ファイル.txt` that might be difficult to type with an English keyboard. Sure, I can find the filename by its extension but what if it does not contain any Latin character at all?

This becomes even more difficult without a graphical environment in which I can easily select the filename and copy from it.

If isn't possible to get a solution similar to the <kbd>TAB</kbd> autocomplete, how could I find this kind of filenames easily?

**I already read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353554/) but has no accepted answer, also I don't know Japanese to input kanjis or similar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the builtin bindings for the readline completion functions seen with:

```
$ bind -p | grep glob
"\eg":   glob-complete-word
"\C-x*": glob-expand-word
"\C-xg": glob-list-expansions
```

You can then type some globbing characters (`*` and `?`) and have them expanded into the line with <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>, or just listed with the other commands.

Comment: How would this help? Wouldn't the globs match all files in the directory? "*.txt" would match too much, and there are no Latin characters to be more specific

Comment: You end up with the filenames in the input line and you can delete the ones you dont want.

Comment: Thank you, this is the closest thing to what I was looking for, although for directories with a lot of files, this might be not as useful. For that matter, I could resort to a script.